# Is there a way of exiting from Gwenview other than killing its window?

Tags: gwenview

How can one exit from gwenview other than by killing its window? I can't find an exit or quit command anywhere.

Comment: Is there no [X] in the corner or the ability to use [Alt]+[F4]? 

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-different-ways-to-end-unresponsive-programs-in-linux/

Comment: Most apps have an action within the app for quitting it. the corner X and [alt]+[F4] are general actions that work for any window.